# OpenGeo 3.0.2 Suite not starting on Windows 8 Pro 64 bit

Tags: boundless-suite, windows-8

I need some help please.

OpenGeo 3.0.2 Suite not starting on Windows 8 Pro 64 bit. The opengeosuite log is empty.

I tried to launch opengeo-suite.bat, the command output is:

```
"Sorry, one argument is required. 
Usage: opengeo-suite [start|stop] [debug] 
C:\Windows\system32>"
```

Comment: How did you try to launch the .bat file? Can you try typing this: *opengeo-suite start* at the command prompt?

Comment: Thanks. The opengeo-suite start command work (I set the command path and the PGDATA variable). I am able to connect to PostGIS in pgAdmin. But the Dashboard still not work. I can send you the Dashboard log if you want.

Comment: If the web applications get launched correctly (GeoServer, GeoExplorer, etc.), you should be able to view a stripped down version of the Dashboard at: http://localhost:8080/dashboard That said, the Dashboard is merely a convenience for linking to the various applications, but isn't necessary for running the Suite. *(Apologies, this was meant as a comment to the thread, not an answer.)*